# For loop executes twice, not sure how to fix

Tags: shell, unix

I have written a shell script. The for loop runs twice. Not sure how to fix this.

Can any one please assist me in resolving the issue?

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p C:/Users/spatro/Desktop/attachment_backup
feed=`sqlplus -s <<EOF
$1/$2
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode rollback
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
select attach_sub_folder from DC_Purge_Files_log where entity_type = 'Attachment' and delete_complete = 'N';
/
exit
EOF`
for counter in $feed
do
mkdir -p C:/Users/spatro/Desktop/attachment_backup/$counter
echo "Sub folder created "$counter
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule number one of safe shellscripting: [Always use quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Your loop *would* have executed once, had the command substitution (the stuff in backticks) and $feed variable been quoted. As it stands, those are asking for trouble! Specifically, word splitting and glob expansion.

If you would like some tooling:

*Shellcheck* would answer your question, and *Naziquote* would fix it (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41104131/2394284) question).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the for loop to execute just once, use a break statement before "done"

for counter in $feed
do
mkdir -p C:/Users/spatro/Desktop/attachment_backup/$counter
echo "Sub folder created "$counter
break
done